# My gem commands keep pointing to a wrong server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Any time I run a gem command (gem install, gem list, etc) I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
Errno::ENETUNREACH: Network is unreachable - connect(2) (<internal_server_at_work>)
```

A while back, before I finally got around to learning Rails, one of the developers made a gem for a project and I made some sort of change to add that server to my gem repositories.

I have no idea where that is. My Gemfile in the project I'm using to teach myself Rails puts rubygems.org as the source. Is there a master Gemfile of some sort?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `Gemfile.lock` specifies some of this information.  Deleting it and rerunning `bundle install` may resolve the problem.

Comment: Are you able to share your Gemfile?  Another consideration may be if you are behind a proxy, I've had that cause big issues with bundler in the past

Answer (score 0):

You can always try `bundle update gem_name`. Also, it is possible to point it to the exact URL.

`gem some_gem, :git => "another url"`

You could also paste your Gemfile for us to help you out better. :)